# lmer in R variable types

Tags: r, categorical-data, lme4-nlme

I'm new to both R and using lmes, and just struggling to work out how I should be preparing my data for the model. I have a data set (dataRT):

```
subject         : num [1:5313] 2830153 2830153 2830153 2830153 2830153 ... 
fiteval         : num [1:5313] 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ... 
gen             : num [1:5313] 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 ... 
evolveto        : num [1:5313] 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 ... 
photo_id        : num [1:5313] 354 44 44 339 354 44 51 44 353 339 ... 
rt              : num [1:5313] 1812 1731 1641 2078 1733 ...
```

and I'm running model

```
model.a=lmer(rtlog ~ gen * fiteval * evolveto + (0 + gen:fiteval:evolveto|subject), data=dataRT, REML = FALSE);
```

As my predictors were binary I didn't alter these, the model ran and CIs were calculated. On considering using photo_id in the model I realised I should perhaps be changing my predictors to factors, which I did using

```
dataRT$evolveto=factor(dataRT$evolveto)
dataRT$gen=factor(dataRT$gen)
dataRT$fiteval=factor(dataRT$fiteval)
dataRT$subject=factor(dataRT$subject)
```

model.a now runs, but gives a singularity error, and CIs will not calculate (repeatedly throwing error=zeta values: using minstepNAs detected in profilingLast two rows have identical or NA).

I'm not sure if this is becasue a) I'm now running the right model, but the fit is just terrible, or that b) I've done something that means the lmer function is not reading the predictors in the right way. None of the predators are ordered, so I assumed factor was the correct approach

Output pre changing to factors is:

```
    Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood . t-tests use Satterthwaite's method [lmerModLmerTest]
    Formula: rtlog ~ gen * fiteval * evolveto + (0 + gen:fiteval:evolveto |      subject)
       Data: dataRT
    
         AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
      3929.6   3995.4  -1954.8   3909.6     5303 
    
    Scaled residuals: 
        Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
    -3.3633 -0.7731 -0.2323  0.6544  2.8007 
    
    Random effects:
     Groups   Name                 Variance Std.Dev.
     subject  gen:fiteval:evolveto 0.002264 0.04758 
     Residual                      0.121920 0.34917 
    Number of obs: 5313, groups:  subject, 50
    
    Fixed effects:
                           Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|)    
    (Intercept)             3.32665    0.01291 5263.23130 257.766  < 2e-16 ***
    gen                     0.04918    0.01946 5263.23130   2.528   0.0115 *  
    fiteval                -0.01935    0.01826 5263.23130  -1.060   0.2892    
    evolveto               -0.01185    0.01838 5263.23130  -0.645   0.5190    
    gen:fiteval             0.32986    0.03074 5263.23130  10.730  < 2e-16 ***
    gen:evolveto           -0.16914    0.02646 5263.23130  -6.392 1.78e-10 ***
    fiteval:evolveto        0.01983    0.02617 5263.23130   0.758   0.4487    
    gen:fiteval:evolveto   -0.27298    0.04063 2203.29013  -6.719 2.33e-11 ***
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
    
    Correlation of Fixed Effects:
                (Intr) gen    fitevl evolvt gn:ftv gn:vlv ftvl:v
    gen         -0.663                                          
    fiteval     -0.707  0.469                                   
    evolveto    -0.702  0.466  0.496                            
    gen:fiteval  0.420 -0.633 -0.594 -0.295                     
    gen:evolvet  0.488 -0.735 -0.345 -0.695  0.465              
    fitevl:vlvt  0.493 -0.327 -0.698 -0.702  0.414  0.488       
    gn:ftvl:vlv -0.318  0.479  0.449  0.452 -0.757 -0.651 -0.644
```

output post changing to factors is

```
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
Model failed to converge with 3 negative eigenvalues: -5.2e-03 -1.0e-02 -1.3e+02Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood . t-tests use Satterthwaite's
  method [lmerModLmerTest]
Formula: rtlog ~ gen * fiteval * evolveto + (0 + gen:fiteval:evolveto |  
    subject)
   Data: dataRT

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 -5291.5  -5018.3   2690.8  -5381.5     3155 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-9.2105 -0.5166  0.0928  0.6632  2.7605 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name                    Variance  Std.Dev. Corr                   
 subject  gen0:fiteval0:evolveto0 1.126e-05 0.003356                        
          gen1:fiteval0:evolveto0 1.839e-05 0.004288  1.00                  
          gen0:fiteval1:evolveto0 2.865e-05 0.005353 -0.43 -0.43            
          gen1:fiteval1:evolveto0 6.735e-05 0.008207  0.61  0.61  0.45      
          gen0:fiteval0:evolveto1 1.409e-04 0.011872  0.79  0.79 -0.31  0.58
          gen1:fiteval0:evolveto1 2.754e-03 0.052481 -0.65 -0.65  0.76  0.09
          gen0:fiteval1:evolveto1 2.028e-04 0.014241 -0.37 -0.37 -0.68 -0.96
          gen1:fiteval1:evolveto1 4.232e-04 0.020571 -0.72 -0.72 -0.29 -0.98
 Residual                         1.062e-02 0.103060                        
                  
                  
                  
                  
                  
                  
 -0.17            
 -0.39 -0.31      
 -0.74 -0.01  0.89
                  
Number of obs: 3200, groups:  subject, 50

Fixed effects:
                          Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)              2.828e+00  5.176e-03  4.729e+02 546.309  < 2e-16 ***
gen1                     1.621e-01  7.291e-03  2.507e+03  22.227  < 2e-16 ***
fiteval1                 4.227e-02  7.368e-03  6.763e+02   5.738 1.45e-08 ***
evolveto1                8.574e-03  7.428e-03  1.384e+02   1.154  0.25041    
gen1:fiteval1           -8.225e-02  1.036e-02  6.479e+02  -7.940 8.94e-15 ***
gen1:evolveto1          -3.221e-01  1.314e-02  5.462e+01 -24.520  < 2e-16 ***
fiteval1:evolveto1      -3.227e-02  1.080e-02  7.474e+01  -2.987  0.00381 ** 
gen1:fiteval1:evolveto1  1.376e-01  1.619e-02  1.147e+02   8.502 7.97e-14 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) gen1   fitvl1 evlvt1 gn1:f1 gn1:v1 ftv1:1
gen1        -0.702                                          
fiteval1    -0.707  0.493                                   
evolveto1   -0.681  0.493  0.474                            
gen1:fitvl1  0.503 -0.702 -0.704 -0.333                     
gen1:evlvt1  0.347 -0.564 -0.195 -0.569  0.358              
ftvl1:vlvt1  0.464 -0.339 -0.678 -0.697  0.458  0.335       
gn1:ftvl1:1 -0.295  0.455  0.395  0.439 -0.623 -0.754 -0.552
optimizer (nloptwrap) convergence code: 0 (OK)
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
```

Thank you all

Edit....removing random slopes... predictors as binary

```
  Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood . t-tests use Satterthwaite's
  method [lmerModLmerTest]
Formula: rtlog ~ gen * fiteval * evolveto + (1 | subject)
   Data: dataRT

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 -5315.5  -5254.8   2667.8  -5335.5     3190 

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-10.2378  -0.5129   0.1025   0.6550   2.8593 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 subject  (Intercept) 0.00000  0.0000  
 Residual             0.01105  0.1051  
Number of obs: 3200, groups:  subject, 50

Fixed effects:
                       Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)           2.828e+00  5.256e-03  3.200e+03 537.979  < 2e-16 ***
gen                   1.618e-01  7.433e-03  3.200e+03  21.770  < 2e-16 ***
fiteval               4.212e-02  7.433e-03  3.200e+03   5.667 1.59e-08 ***
evolveto              8.047e-03  7.433e-03  3.200e+03   1.083  0.27909    
gen:fiteval          -8.176e-02  1.051e-02  3.200e+03  -7.778 9.89e-15 ***
gen:evolveto         -3.208e-01  1.051e-02  3.200e+03 -30.516  < 2e-16 ***
fiteval:evolveto     -3.169e-02  1.051e-02  3.200e+03  -3.015  0.00259 ** 
gen:fiteval:evolveto  1.348e-01  1.487e-02  3.200e+03   9.070  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) gen    fitevl evolvt gn:ftv gn:vlv ftvl:v
gen         -0.707                                          
fiteval     -0.707  0.500                                   
evolveto    -0.707  0.500  0.500                            
gen:fiteval  0.500 -0.707 -0.707 -0.354                     
gen:evolvet  0.500 -0.707 -0.354 -0.707  0.500              
fitevl:vlvt  0.500 -0.354 -0.707 -0.707  0.500  0.500       
gn:ftvl:vlv -0.354  0.500  0.500  0.500 -0.707 -0.707 -0.707
optimizer (nloptwrap) convergence code: 0 (OK)
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular

Computing profile confidence intervals ...
                            2.5 %      97.5 %
.sig01                0.000000000  0.00824694
.sigma                0.102600485  0.10775337
(Intercept)           2.817430680  2.83804086
gen                   0.147254388  0.17640158
fiteval               0.027548585  0.05669577
evolveto             -0.006526536  0.02262065
gen:fiteval          -0.102372435 -0.06115208
gen:evolveto         -0.341412653 -0.30019230
fiteval:evolveto     -0.052300721 -0.01108037
gen:fiteval:evolveto  0.105694253  0.16398863
```

removing random slopes... predictors as factors get the exact same output:

```
 Models:
model.a: rtlog ~ gen * fiteval * evolveto + (1 | subject)  #predictors as binary
model.b: rtlog ~ gen * fiteval * evolveto + (1 | subject)  #predictors as factors
        npar     AIC     BIC logLik deviance Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)
model.a   10 -5315.5 -5254.8 2667.8  -5335.5                    
model.b   10 -5315.5 -5254.8 2667.8  -5335.5     0  0
```

Although both models now appear to have issues with fitting.

Comment: Since gen, fiteval, and evolveto are all binary variables, there should be no difference in the model when you make them factors. The only thing I see you are doing different is that in the first formula, you told it not to include a intercept for the random effects but in the second formula, you have an intercept (gen:fiteval:evolveto | subject). You have too many parameters and you can see that in the output, but it still looks weird to me. Could you try refitting the first model but use this formula:  rtlog ~ gen * fiteval * evolveto + (1| subject)

Comment: Thank you for you response, sorry for the mistake, I've edited the above (I had pasted wrong output, but the issue still remained which exactly the same formula.

Comment: Your suggestion does make both models give the same output, but now I have a fitting issue for both. When you say, "you have too many parameters", are you suggesting I simplify the model? I could, theoretically, run 2 lmers, splitting dataRT by $evolveto and just consider intercepts and not slopes. Thank you again.

Comment: In the first model output it shows only one thing under random effects:      subject  gen:fiteval:evolveto 0.002264 0.04758.  But, in the second model (treating the variables as factors), it has 8 different estimated random effects. The difference in AIC is very large, too. I can't figure out what is going on. Can you post a link to the dataset or a simulated dataset?

Comment: Ok , I see you used formula: rtlog ~ gen * fiteval * evolveto + (0 + gen:fiteval:evolveto |   subject). You used * in the fixed effects but : in the random effects. Can you try using * in both places?

Comment: Hi, exchanging : for * is also not running. I've just created a fake dataset to share (note there will be some differences in df's as I randomly removed rows to create missing trials, but it is representative of my data). It is available here https://www.dropbox.com/sh/txjn1eunqwo9mg5/AABwO-7ZZ6lNS6bofrxNVBDQa?dl=0

Comment: Also  to note, I've added photo_id to that dataset. It is clear if you use this as a fixed effect predictor (with 6 levels) that something is different with the fixed effect outputs and model summaries. i.e using rtlog ~ gen * photo_id * evolveto + (1| subject) before and after changing photo_id to a factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to download your program and dataset from the link.

In your original dataset, you have 50 subjects and 5313 observations (about 100 per subject). So, there should be enough data there to estimate 8 random effects per subject plus the 8 fixed effects in the model.

I don't know why it has trouble estimating them since you have about 100 observations per subject. Do all (or many) of the subjects have at least one observation for each of the combination of factors? If not, that could be the problem. Maybe you will need to specify a compound symmetric covariance matrix for the random effects.

One thing that is helpful to understand the models is looking at the predictions. I think it is really helpful to look at the predictions within a subject and across subjects to understand the model better.

These are the population predictions (level 0):
p0 <- predict(model.a,re.form=NA)
For the population predictions, the only thing used in the model is the covariates, so all subjects will have the same predictions given the same combination of the covariates.

These are the individual predictions (including the random effects for each subject)
p1 <- predict(model.a)
Those will be different across subjects for the same combination of covariates if there is a random effect for that combination.

So, (p1-p0) will give you the difference, which is just the estimated random effects.

When you use the random effect this way with the numerical covariates (not factors):
(0 + gen:fiteval:evolveto | subject)
there is only one random effect per subject and that only applies for the case where all three binary covariates are 1.

When you use the random effect this way:
(gen:fiteval:evolveto | subject)
there are two random effects per subject. One applies for the case where all three binary covariates are 1 and the other applies for all the other 7 combinations of the binary covariates.

When you use the random effect this way:
(gen*fiteval*evolveto | subject)
there are eight random effects per subject. One for each of the 8 combinations of the binary covariates.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to look at data, my real data has equivalent trial numbers and I'll read up on specifying compound symmetric covariance matrices. Thank you also for the very comprehensive description of why RFX outputs were differing.